# Phishing email linking to sharepoint address

Tags: email, phishing, email-spoofing

Our organization got some sort of phishing email that contained an attachment which linked to sharepoint - ie. `https://someaddress.sharepoint.com/:b:/...` etc. The link takes you to that "sharepoint" site with a button to click and download the pdf.

Is it possible for the website to plant a virus on the computer to compromise it, or does the file need to be downloaded in order to compromise the machine?